# OpenIddict Request header when using Reference Tokens

Tags: authentication, openiddict

I am using OpenIddict. When I use Opaque tokens (default), authentication works for me if in every request I include the following header,

Authorization: Bearer [token]

When I change configuration to use Reference tokens, I get a 401.

I noted that the issued token length is different when I use Reference Tokens. Should I change Authorization header?

Here my OpenIddict config

```
.AddServer(options =>
       {
           options.UseMvc();

           options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");

           // Set the access toke lifetime
           options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

           // Enable the password flow.
           options.AllowPasswordFlow();

           // Accept anonymous clients (i.e clients that don't send a client_id).
           options.AcceptAnonymousClients();

           options.DisableHttpsRequirement();

           options.EnableRevocationEndpoint("/api/revoke");

           options.UseReferenceTokens();

           options.UseRollingTokens();
       })
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please include your validation configuration? (`.AddValidation(...)`)

Comment: Hi! Maybe that's the issue. Currently only ".AddValidation();" without extra info. Am I missing something else? Thanks again!